# unzipコマンドでzipファイルの解凍が出来ない

Tags: linux

例えば`sample.zip`というファイルが存在するディレクトリで、

`unzip sample.zip`

コマンドを実行するとファイルの解凍は実行されず、
代わりにunzipコマンドの使用方法のみが表示されます。

```
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.

Usage: unzip [-Z] [-opts[modifiers]] file[.zip] [list] [-x xlist] [-d exdir]
  Default action is to extract files in list, except those in xlist, to exdir;
  file[.zip] may be a wildcard.  -Z => ZipInfo mode ("unzip -Z" for usage).

  -p  extract files to pipe, no messages     -l  list files (short format)
  -f  freshen existing files, create none    -t  test compressed archive data
  -u  update files, create if necessary      -z  display archive comment only
  -v  list verbosely/show version info       -T  timestamp archive to latest
  -x  exclude files that follow (in xlist)   -d  extract files into exdir
modifiers:
  -n  never overwrite existing files         -q  quiet mode (-qq => quieter)
  -o  overwrite files WITHOUT prompting      -a  auto-convert any text files
  -j  junk paths (do not make directories)   -aa treat ALL files as text
  -C  match filenames case-insensitively     -L  make (some) names lowercase
  -X  restore UID/GID info                   -V  retain VMS version numbers
  -K  keep setuid/setgid/tacky permissions   -M  pipe through "more" pager
See "unzip -hh" or unzip.txt for more help.  Examples:
  unzip data1 -x joe   => extract all files except joe from zipfile data1.zip
  unzip -p foo | more  => send contents of foo.zip via pipe into program more
  unzip -fo foo ReadMe => quietly replace existing ReadMe if archive file newer
```

なぜ

`unzip «ZIPファイル名»`

のような形式でコマンドが実行できないのですか？

実行環境は **Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS** です。

Comment: 念の為： そのディレクトリで `ls ≪ZIPファイル名≫` としたときにちゃんとそのファイルが出てきますか？　ファイル名は `[a-z]+.zip` の形式ですか？（違うのであれば、適切にクォートやエスケープできていますか？）

Comment: unzip をフルパスで指定しても ( `/usr/bin/unzip sample.zip` ) 実行結果は同じですか?

Comment: `unzip -sample.zip`のように`-`を誤って消し忘れた時に同一の症状になりますが…`unzip -Z sample.zip`にしても同一のメッセージが表示されるでしょうか？それとも`unzip -Z`を実行した時に出るメッセージに変化するでしょうか？

Comment: lsコマンドにてファイルが存在していることは確認できました。また、ファイルの名前はアルファベット以外は使用していません。

Comment: フルパスで実行すると、正常に解凍が行えました `/usr/bin/unzip sample.zip`。

Comment: `unzip -Z sample.zip` では、結果は上とは異なるメッセージが表示されました。`ZipInfo 3.00 of 20 April 2009, by Greg Roelofs and the Info-ZIP group. ...`

Comment: unzipのパスを確認した所、linuxbrewのunzipに書き換わっているようでした。 `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/unzip`

Answer (score 2):

unzipコマンドのパスがbinフォルダ内の

`/usr/bin/unzip`

でなく、linuxbrewの

`/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/unzip`

に置き換わっていたことが原因でした。

そのため、フルパスで`/usr/bin/unzip` を実行すれば、意図した通りにunzipが動作することが確認できました。

Comment: こちら、linuxbrewのunzipコマンドにバグがある（or あった）ということなんでしょうか……？

Comment: バグの可能性も考えられます。
確認したところ、linuxbrew版、/usr/bin版いずれのunzipコマンドもバージョンは同じ `UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009,` でした。
それらに対し、同一のコマンド `unzip sample.zip` を実行したにもかかわらず、結果が異なりました。